# Different upload and download urls for Django Models's Image Field

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I need a way to have different upload and download URLs for ImageField. I want to upload the image to AWS S3 and while accessing the image I want the image to route through CDN (in my case Fastly).

```
def get_avatar_upload_path(identity, filename):
    file_ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    file_name = f'{uuid.uuid4()}.{file_ext}'
    return f'{settings.AWS_MEDIA_PREFIX}{identity.uuid}/{file_name}'

class Identity(identity_revision_base):
    """
    Identity model. Ties a user to a chat identity.
    """
    badges = models.ManyToManyField(Badge, blank=True)
    key = models.UUIDField(_("key"), unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    uuid = models.UUIDField(_("UUID"), unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_avatar_upload_path, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="+",
    )
```

Just like I am specifying upload path in ImageField, I would like a way to do something similar for accessing Image. It also seems that I cannot modify avatar.url once it is created. Is there any way around?

If there is any way, I can override the Model's behaviour to modify the url while accessing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)? It takes care of uploading to object store and returns CDN URLs for downloading. Fastly is S3 compatible so it should work.

In general you can also also use [model methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#model-methods) with property decorator for getting a custom calculated value from model instances.

Comment: Can I use model methods with avatar field in above model? if yes then how?

Comment: Or if there is a way, I can upload the image to different url and save different url in ImageField

Comment: ImageField inherits from FileField so it has to be a “file” not an URL. You can use URLField to store urls. For the image you can add a new method avatar_url with @property decorator and add your logic there. Then you can fetch it by `my_identity.avatar_url`.